# Data Context is error when adding in ASP.Net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'm not sure if this is the right section to post so please whoever it may be, don't be angry with me as I'm desperate and stuck

I received this error message when loading my application. I am using VS 2022 Pro and here is the error/problem I receive:

> BC30516: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.

The error message is pointing directly to the line of code below:

```
Protected Sub showAll()
Dim db As New StudentDataDataContext
```

and here is the rest of the code that goes with it:

```vb
Dim Marks = From Mark In db.Marks _
Select New With {Mark.ModuleInformation.ModuleCode, Mark.ModuleName, Mark.Marks, Mark.Grade, Mark.ModuleInformation.Credit, Mark.Comments, Mark.ModuleInformation.ModuleInformation}
GridView1.DataSource = Marks
GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Please could somebody help me as I am stuck and do not know what to do to solve the problem?

Thank you to anybody who helped me in advance

Comment: Please also show the code of the `new` constructor of the `StudentDataDataContext` class.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know what you mean. I am new to LinQ in ASP.Net so I don't what error is this. I used this same code when I was creating a connection using LinQ to SQL in WinForms but when I tried to use the same code in ASP. Net, that error occurs.